# Patient safety culture

Tags: research, safety

I would like to ask if anybody here can suggest me places where I can get open access to papers under the topic of the behavior of patient safety. I am doing a research on this subject but the institution I am working in is not academia, therefore people around me are not quite well informed about such information.

Answer (score 1):

A full college library should have what you need. They typically have most major research journals. Some large municipal libraries will too. Smaller libraries may have material on the subject, but they probably won't have access to research journals.

And of course many research papers are available free online. Abstracts for almost all research is available for free, but full text may be behind pay walls. But the abstracts alone will often be all you need, and if you need the full article it at least gives you the exact publication you need to find.